# Issue with select2 not being able to add new condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

So, I'm having a bit of an issue with select2. I tried multiple ways to do a workaround but I wasn't able to solve this issue.
[I have this thing that I want to add some filters with 3 sections each filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTfWf.png)

My plan is, if someone clicks on the "Add condition", it will add 3 new selects, similar to the first ones.
The issue is, when I click on the button, the the new ones works but the old ones does not work.

Can anyone help me?

```html
Here is a working JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/souocare/y1jme0hp/25/
```

Comment: use `insertAdjacentHTML()` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov where? can you change on the jsfiddle? I never used that function and I don't know where to apply it. Thanks!

Comment: @s.kuznetsov not necessary, I think I got it! Thank you so much! Here is the new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/souocare/one80hgx/10/